# Automatic routing when connecting a usb network adapter

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, network-interface, raspbian

The gateway is not set automatically when connecting a USB network adapter in R-PI.
I want to set it automatically, what should I do?

Comment: you're using DHCP to configure it?  Then you're not pusing a gateway.  Do you have an existing interface configured?  It might be you're not _using_ the usb gateway because your other route is being preferred.  Show us the output of some commands and what you're seeing.  This is too vague to answer.

Comment: @Daniel Farrell I don't know what I need to show you something so you can clearly see it.
Tell me what I can show you to understand
Thanks